# Как внутрь класса подключить константы из другого файла

Tags: php

Приведу примитивный пример как бы хотелось:

```
сlass MyClass
{
  //подключить file.php
}

//file.php содержит

const MY_CONST = 'My Value';

//в итоге получить

MyClass::MY_CONST;
```

Сам *file.php* может иметь абсолютно разное название. Есть варианты реализации?

Comment: А в этом есть смысл такой?

Прикинь у тебя поменяется файл и придется лезть в код класса чтобы исправить имя. Я бы другим путем пошел.

Гы гы гы, создай класс с твоими дефолтными значениями и сделай 
> сlass MyClass extends MyDefault

Хотя и это не айс, но все-таки меньше геморроя, если ты действительно хочешь юзать переменные из файла. :)

Comment: Гы прикинь скрипт будет знать что файл поменялся от определенной зависимости и будет подбирать файл учитывая эту зависимость!

Answer (score 1):

Должно работать, потому как они суперглобальные. Только подключить нада константы до  использования класса .

```
PHP 5.3+  
const MY_CONST = 'My Value';

PHP 5.2  
define('MY_CONST', 'My Value');
```

Comment: Чувствую подвох в том что ТС написал код и опробовал его и не получилось.

Comment: файл подключен до использования класса в топике

Comment: @Shrek ТС написал что на выходе хочет получить MyClass::MY_CONST;)))
Если так реализовать нет возможности, то конечно проще юзать define и не морочить очко)